.Net Aspire The 'applicationUrl' setting must be an https address unless the 'ASPIRE_ALLOW_UNSECURED_TRANSPORT' environment variable is set to true
I am getting the below error while running the .net aspire starter application.
'One or more errors occurred. (The 'applicationUrl' setting must be an https address unless the 'ASPIRE_ALLOW_UNSECURED_TRANSPORT' environment variable is set to true. This configuration is commonly set in the launch profile. See https://aka.ms/dotnet/aspire/allowunsecuredtransport for more details.)'



What is the value of the applicationUrl setting and the value of the ASPIRE_ALLOW_UNSECURED_TRANSPORT environment variable, if set?

able to fix the issue @Progman

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

In the AppHost project go to the Properties folder, then open launchSettings.json and add this line to the environmentVariables.
"ASPIRE_ALLOW_UNSECURED_TRANSPORT": "true"

Your launchSettings.json should become like this :

Now you can run your Aspire AppHost project as well.
For more information read here
